# firefox: show bookmark toolbar in fullscreen mode

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

I want the bookmark toolbar appears when I move my cursor to the top of screen, when I in fullscreen mode.

The bookmarks in the bookmark toolbar is the most frequently used bookmarks, so I need to visit them frequently.

I'm also using Vimperator, is there a command that only list out the bookmarks in bookmark toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but here is a link that says you need a firefox addon.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1039009

Comment: The link you provided is very useful, I've solved this problem using the code they provided, not an extension

Comment: Could you please edit in the useful code/extension links? The link to the forum could change, or otherwise go dead, meaning this answer wouldn't be useful then.

Comment: @Wilf I've add the method, you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

The code is below, it is from [mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1039009):

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

/* full screen toolbars */
#navigator-toolbox toolbar[moz-collapsed="true"]:not([collapsed="true"]) {
 visibility:visible!important;
}
```

Steps:

- Create the chrome folder (lowercase) in the .default profile folder if this folder doesn't exist. The `<xxxxx>.default` folder is under `~/.molliza/` folder, i.e. where firefox stores its profiles.  `<xxxxxx>` is some weried strings different for each computer.
- Use a plain text editor like vim to create a (new) userChrome.css file in the chrome folder (file name is case sensitive)
- Paste the code in the userChrome.css file in the editor window
  Make sure that the userChrome.css file starts with the default @namespace line

The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

As of Firefox 68, Firefox does not (by default) check for a custom `userChrome.css` file. Thus, the was I solved this problem on my computer was in two steps.

## 1. Create `userChrome.css`

In `~/.mozilla/<profile code>.<profile name>/` create a directory named `chrome`. In the chrome directory, create a file named `userChrome.css` with the following contents:

```
/*
   Override hiding of Bookmarks Toolbar in F11 full screen
   when you roll down the tabs/main toolbar 
    src: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1212156?fpa=1
    and https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html
*/
#navigator-toolbox[inFullscreen="true"] #PersonalToolbar {
  visibility: unset !important;
}
```

## 2. Configure Firefox to look for `userChrome.css` at startup.

Copied from [userchrome.org](https://www.userchrome.org/firefox-changes-userchrome-css.html#fx69).

> To make startup faster for most users, Firefox 69 will no longer look for this file automatically. You need to tell it to look. Here's how:
>
> 1. In a new tab, type or paste **about:config** in the address bar and press Enter/Return. Click the button accepting the risk.
> 2. In the search box above the list, type or paste **userprof** and pause while the list is filtered. If you do not see anything on the list, please ignore the rest of these instructions. You can close this tab now.
> 3. If the **toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets** preference is not already set to **true**, double-click it to switch the value from false to true.
>
> That change should take effect on your next startup.